# How to use Power BI Desktop without uploading data into its cloud

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cloud, business-intelligence, powerbi

I want to use Power BI Desktop within my MVC application. All I could find about this is coupled with uploading the data [[1]](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-a-new-power-api-asp-net-web-sample/), [[2]](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-power-bi-publish-to-web/) into a cloud but that is not an option for me since I am working with sensible company data. Is there any workaround you know off?

And if not so are there any alternatives?

Comment: Power BI allows you to publish the Power BI Desktop files into the locally hosted Pyramid Analytics server (3rd party solution) [link](http://www.inzeek.net/cloud/microsoft-power-bi-on-premises/)

Comment: Please write an answer since this is what I was looking for. I just do not want to load any datan into the clould not the data but also not the report itself.

Comment: I haven't used the Pyramid solution. I was searching for same thing you are, found it, and then happened to see this question and left it as suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is using a [Power BI Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-gateway-enterprise/).  This will create a connection to your local data stores.  In order to display a power bi report inside an mvc application you would still need to create the pbix and upload it to the power bi service.  Using the gateway will allow direct queries to your local data, and **not** force you to store your data in the cloud.

Once you have the report uploaded to powerbi service you can follow his article [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-a-power-bi-tile-or-report/) on how to embed a tile or report into your application.

I have successfully been able to embed a report into my MVC application using the above article, I however have not tried out the Gateway because my data already lives in azure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Power BI embedded does not allow direct query, as of now it only supports import data.

Comment: This question is not talking about PowerBI Embedded, so I am not sure how the comment relates.  I have also found that Power BI Embedded DOES support direct query.  Do you have a link to documentation that explains otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use [Power Bi Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/get-started) (PBRS).  It is a solution you can purchase a license for and install locally to serve embedded/integrated reports of your company's sensitive data.  PBRS implements automatic data refresh so your reports will contain the latest data without having to upload a new reports.

Prerequsites will be a local SQL Server Enterprise instance and reports will need to be developed with [Power Bi Desktop optimized for Power Bi Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/install-powerbi-desktop).  If you are already familiar with PBI Desktop, it is almost exactly the same and you can port them between with little to no issues.

The following [thread](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Embed-Power-BI-report-in-web-application-using-Power-BI-Report/td-p/305677) verifies 2 separate approaches on embedding reports: 1) embed reports within an Iframe, or 2) have the reports filter with row level security based on the users role within the application.

Microsoft is currently making quarterly updates and improvements to the software (the most recent was Sep 2018).

There is a very active [community](https://community.powerbi.com) of people developing Power Bi reports, custom visuals, admins and dbas to help and support.  Post to the forums if you can't get help repost it here.

If the interface looks familiar, PBRS was developed by rebranding a prior version of SSRS.  If you want to try it out before you purchase the license, the software is available with the same functionality on a 180 day trial.

Answer (score 0):

On Premise hosting of Power BI is coming. A preview of this feature is available here in the form of an Azure VM.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2016/10/25/announcing-a-technical-preview-of-power-bi-reports-in-sql-server-reporting-services/